# Zend db profiler doesn't track queries in view/layout

Tags: zend-framework, profiling

I have a Zend app build in a 1.something version. For debug/efficiency testing I have the profiler up and running but it doesn't take the queries from the layout and/or view in account.

These queries are run by the help of view helpers, which communicate with the corresponding models.

In my database ini file I have activated the profiler and I can see all "normal" controller based queries (most of them also communicate by the corresponding models) in the footer of my layout. The other ones are missing, any ideas?

Comment: Obvious question but I assume you're outputting your DB profile data after the view helpers have been called?

Comment: The profiler data is in the bottom of the footer, which is in the layout.phtml. I guess that's a yes..?

Comment: That was a No. I had fetch the profiler data in the postDispatch method of the controller. Apparently this is fired _before_ the view helpers. Solution was a view helper of it's own. Thanks for the heads up.